# Проверка орфограмм неологизмами

Tags: орфография, неологизмы, безударные-гласные

Почему неологизмами нельзя проверять безударные гласные? Допустим, если проверить слово "симпатичный" неологизмом "симпотненький", то можно допустить ошибку. Что, неологизмы созданы специально, чтобы сбивать с толку школьников?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем проверять безударные гласные жаргонными словами, многие из которые распространены в устной речи и, следовательно, отсутствуют в нормативных словарях,с чем связаны разночтения в написании некоторых жаргонизмов.

Comment: К тому же слово ''симпатичный'' можно проверить  словом ''симпатия'', где безударная гласная стоит под ударением.

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит проверять орфограмму жаргонными словечками, созданнымии не совсем грамотными людьми. Наверняка тот, кто придумал слово "симпОтнеький", был уверен, что слово "симпАтичный" пишется с О. Для проверки подбираем слова нормированного русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Симпатия, симпатичный - слова нейтрального стиля, но при этом в словаре ненормативной лексики отмечаются просторечные варианты слов с тем же корнем: симпатяга, симпотный (отсюда - симпотненький), симпатюшка. Эти слова применяются в разговорной речи, в том числе в художественной литературе для речевой характеристики героев.

Итак, симпатичный - симпотный, перегласовка А/О при смене ударения. Такая перегласовка не редкость для русского языка (например: заработать – зарабатывать, усвоить – усваивать, загореть - загар), так выбирается удобная фонетическая форма слова.

Поэтому надо иметь в виду, что не каждый корневой гласный можно проверить ударением. А в данном варианте мы вообще имеем две ударные позиции гласного, поэтому проверку в принципе сделать нельзя, это корень с чередованием А/О. А - это основная форма, которая пишется в ударной и безударной позиции, а О - ударная перегласовка (встречается в ненормативных  словах).

Comment: Sibylla,  безударные гласные не проверяются словами с чередующимися гласными в корне. Так же как и глагольные корни  с формами совершенного вида на - ивать(ывать).

Comment: Не проверяются, конечно, именно чередование не позволяет это сделать. И именно чередование (а не просторечная форма) не позволяет использовать "симпотненький"  для проверки "симпатичный". Поэтому ответ такой: дело не в том, что это неологизм, жаргонное словечко, а в том, что это неологизм с перегласовкой гласных.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что здесь именно чередование? Как вообще можно говорить о чередовании в жаргонных словах? Да и потом, в слове симпатичный - симпатия -  симпотный нет корней с чередующимися гласными.  Есть корень с безударной гласной.

Comment: Симпат/и/я - симпат/ичн/ый, симпат/изирова/ть, корень симпат-. Симпат/и/я - симпот/н/ый, симпот/н/еньк/ий, корень симпот-. Итак, с учетом ненормативных слов, симпат/симпот, чередование А/О в корне.  При образовании жаргонных слов используются те же способы и те же морфемы, что и для слов обычных. За такими словами даже интересно наблюдать, такая своеобразная творческая мастерская.

Comment: А на чем основано чередование? Как можно объяснить здесь чередование: когда пишется о, когда а? В обоих словах под ударением а и о.

Comment: Я думаю, что даже некоторые классические корни с чередованием  можно связать  с перегласовкой и выделить среди них основную форму. Например, корень твар-/твор-. Форма твор-, по-видимому,  основная, так как творить - делать твердым, а тварь - ударная перегласовка ("творь" плохо звучит), также гореть - основной корень гор-, а гарь, угар, загар, нагар - перегласовки. Поэтому в нашем случае, конечно, основной формой является корень симпат- (pathos - страсть, болезнь, известное слово), а симпот- всего лишь перегласовка, да еще в ненормированной лексике. Эту форму можно вообще не учитывать.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что в самой постановке вопроса уже содержится ошибка.
"Симпотненький" не является неологизмом. Оно не является общеупотребительным. Это называется эрратив. Или "какография". Умышленное искажение языка. Если понятнее - "олбанский" :) Поскольку не является частью какого-либо арго, слэнга, жаргона. Простое коверканье языка.

Надеюсь, вам не очень хочется говорить "какографией"? :)
"За сим, потненький, прощаюсь!"

Comment: Артем, олбанский - это искаженная орфография( причем преднамеренная) уже существующего слова.  В нашем случае - это жаргон.

Comment: Жаргон - речь какой-н. социальной или иной объединённой общими интересами группы...    К какой конкретной социальной группе относятся люди употребляющие слово "симпотненький"?

Comment: Скорее всего молодежный.

Comment: Ни в коем случае! Если так говорит 0.001% молодёжи, это не является ни сленгом, ни жаргоном, поскольку не является признаком социальной группы. Это именно - какография. К тому же, это из речи Эллочек Людоедочек.

Comment: Какография - умышленно ошибочное правописание, как дидактический прием. Где в этом слове умышленная ошибка?

Comment: Пардном, рази симпотненький эта не умышлённое искожение словчика? Радное серце! :)  (Только в качестве примера)

Comment: Какого слова? Разве слово "симпАтненький"?

Comment: Слова "симпатичный". Других слов в литературном русском языке нет. Единственное исключение, пожалуй, можно сделать для "симпатюшечка" и "симпатяга". :) (похоже, автоматика нас уже предупреждает об излишне длинном обсуждении)

Comment: Вы не понимаете значение слова "какография". Какография - ошибка в слова, а не новое слово. Пример: мидвед вместо ***медведь***

Comment: Давайте так - вы не понимаете значения слова "жаргон", я не понимаю, что понятие эрратив относится к письменной речи. Хорошо? Но меня извиняет факт, что ,в данном случае, слово было написано. Чёрным по-русски. Но от того, что это слово можно употребить в устной речи, оно не стало жаргонным! И ещё - подобные слова не являются "новыми" словами. "Симпатюлетюрненький" не является новым словом. Оно является исковерканным старым словом.

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю слово жаргон. Слово "симпотненький" относительное новое.  Ничем иначе как жаргоном его не назовешь. Это слово за пределами литературной нормы. Поэтому ни чем иначе, как жаргонно-просторечным словом не назовешь его.